# Grabbing the Google Calendar ID when clicking on any event in the calendar (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm creating a Chrome Extension that's meant to work with Google Calendar.  I'm trying to grab the event ID onclick on any meeting / event within the calendar.  I can't find any documentation on how to grab this id. I need the id when .bubblemain is up.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, do you find out how to get it yet?

Comment: Afraid not.  I gave up.  I think the answer is that it can't be done.